# RestKit - Crash on iOS 8

Tags: objective-c, ios8, restkit, restkit-0.20, ios8.1

My application is working perfect on iOS 7.x. But on iOS 8.1 it crashes after mapping.

Here is the Log

```
2014-11-24 22:04:24.807 myapp[15398:835953] T restkit.network:RKObjectRequestOperation.m:178 GET 'http://api-test.myapp.com/meetings?type=past&page=1&text=&with=&about=':
request.headers={
    Accept = "application/json";
    "Accept-Language" = "en;q=1";
    "User-Agent" = "myapp/25 (iPad Simulator; iOS 8.1; Scale/1.00)";
}
request.body=(null)
2014-11-24 22:04:25.100 myapp[15398:836040] T restkit.network:RKResponseMapperOperation.m:451 Mapping HTTP response to nil target object...
2014-11-24 22:04:25.102 myapp[15398:836040] D restkit.object_mapping:RKMapperOperation.m:297 Found mappable collection at keyPath '': (
        {
        "created_at" = "2014-11-24T20:40:05+05:00";
        deleted = 0;
        "finish_time" = "2014-11-24T16:40:05Z";
        "follow_up_id" = "<null>";
        id = 92465;
        location = "<null>";
        lock = 0;
        "optional_participants" =         (
        );
        organizer =         {
            email = "testemail.1000@gmail.com";
            id = 43031;
            name = "iOS 8";
        };
        "parent_meeting_id" = "<null>";
        "parent_meeting_title" = "<null>";
        "readonly_participants" =         (
        );
        "required_participants" =         (
        );
        sample = 0;
        "start_time" = "2014-11-24T15:40:05Z";
        tags =         (
        );
        title = "Untitled Meeting";
        topics =         (
        );
        "total_topics" = 0;
        "updated_at" = "2014-11-24T20:40:05+05:00";
    }
)
2014-11-24 22:04:25.105 myapp[15398:836040] D restkit.core_data:RKFetchRequestManagedObjectCache.m:124 Found objects '(
)' using fetchRequest '<NSFetchRequest: 0x7b8a64c0> (entity: DBMeetings; predicate: (id == 92465); sortDescriptors: ((null)); type: NSManagedObjectResultType; )'
2014-11-24 22:04:25.105 myapp[15398:836184] D restkit.object_mapping:RKPropertyInspector.m:130 Cached property inspection for Class 'DBMeetings': {
    "created_at" =     {
        isPrimitive = 0;
        keyValueCodingClass = NSDate;
        name = "created_at";
    };
    "finish_date" =     {
        isPrimitive = 0;
        keyValueCodingClass = NSDate;
        name = "finish_date";
    };
    "finish_time" =     {
        isPrimitive = 0;
        keyValueCodingClass = NSDate;
        name = "finish_time";
    };
    "follow_up_id" =     {
        isPrimitive = 0;
        keyValueCodingClass = NSNumber;
        name = "follow_up_id";
    };
    id =     {
        isPrimitive = 0;
        keyValueCodingClass = NSNumber;
        name = id;
    };
    "is_synced" =     {
        isPrimitive = 0;
        keyValueCodingClass = NSNumber;
        name = "is_synced";
    };
    location =     {
        isPrimitive = 0;
        keyValueCodingClass = NSString;
        name = location;
    };
    lock =     {
        isPrimitive = 0;
        keyValueCodingClass = NSNumber;
        name = lock;
    };
    "meeting_topics" =     {
        isPrimitive = 0;
        keyValueCodingClass = NSSet;
        name = "meeting_topics";
    };
    "optional_participants" =     {
        isPrimitive = 0;
        keyValueCodingClass = NSSet;
        name = "optional_participants";
    };
    organizer =     {
        isPrimitive = 0;
        keyValueCodingClass = DBMembers;
        name = organizer;
    };
    "parent_meeting_id" =     {
        isPrimitive = 0;
        keyValueCodingClass = NSNumber;
        name = "parent_meeting_id";
    };
    "parent_meeting_title" =     {
        isPrimitive = 0;
        keyValueCodingClass = NSString;
        name = "parent_meeting_title";
    };
    "readonly_participants" =     {
        isPrimitive = 0;
        keyValueCodingClass = NSSet;
        name = "readonly_participants";
    };
    "required_participants" =     {
        isPrimitive = 0;
        keyValueCodingClass = NSSet;
        name = "required_participants";
    };
    sample =     {
        isPrimitive = 0;
        keyValueCodingClass = NSNumber;
        name = sample;
    };
    shouldBeDeleted =     {
        isPrimitive = 0;
        keyValueCodingClass = NSNumber;
        name = shouldBeDeleted;
    };
    "start_date" =     {
        isPrimitive = 0;
        keyValueCodingClass = NSDate;
        name = "start_date";
    };
    "start_time" =     {
        isPrimitive = 0;
        keyValueCodingClass = NSDate;
        name = "start_time";
    };
    tags =     {
        isPrimitive = 0;
        keyValueCodingClass = NSSet;
        name = tags;
    };
    title =     {
        isPrimitive = 0;
        keyValueCodingClass = NSString;
        name = title;
    };
    "topics_updated_at" =     {
        isPrimitive = 0;
        keyValueCodingClass = NSDate;
        name = "topics_updated_at";
    };
    "total_topics" =     {
        isPrimitive = 0;
        keyValueCodingClass = NSNumber;
        name = "total_topics";
    };
    "updated_at" =     {
        isPrimitive = 0;
        keyValueCodingClass = NSDate;
        name = "updated_at";
    };
}
2014-11-24 22:04:25.112 myapp[15398:836040] D restkit.object_mapping:RKMapperOperation.m:231 Asked to map source object {
    "created_at" = "2014-11-24T20:40:05+05:00";
    deleted = 0;
    "finish_time" = "2014-11-24T16:40:05Z";
    "follow_up_id" = "<null>";
    id = 92465;
    location = "<null>";
    lock = 0;
    "optional_participants" =     (
    );
    organizer =     {
        email = "testemail.1000@gmail.com";
        id = 43031;
        name = "iOS 8";
    };
    "parent_meeting_id" = "<null>";
    "parent_meeting_title" = "<null>";
    "readonly_participants" =     (
    );
    "required_participants" =     (
    );
    sample = 0;
    "start_time" = "2014-11-24T15:40:05Z";
    tags =     (
    );
    title = "Untitled Meeting";
    topics =     (
    );
    "total_topics" = 0;
    "updated_at" = "2014-11-24T20:40:05+05:00";
} with mapping <RKEntityMapping:0x7b941ee0 objectClass=DBMeetings propertyMappings=(
    "<RKAttributeMapping: 0x7b943420 id => id>",
    "<RKAttributeMapping: 0x7b943180 total_topics => total_topics>",
    "<RKAttributeMapping: 0x7b9431a0 title => title>",
    "<RKAttributeMapping: 0x7b943450 finish_time => finish_time>",
    "<RKAttributeMapping: 0x7b943490 finish_date => finish_date>",
    "<RKAttributeMapping: 0x7b943430 start_time => start_time>",
    "<RKAttributeMapping: 0x7b9435c0 updated_at => updated_at>",
    "<RKAttributeMapping: 0x7b943510 parent_meeting_id => parent_meeting_id>",
    "<RKAttributeMapping: 0x7b943520 created_at => created_at>",
    "<RKAttributeMapping: 0x7b943540 parent_meeting_title => parent_meeting_title>",
    "<RKAttributeMapping: 0x7b9437c0 meeting_topics.updated_at => topics_updated_at>",
    "<RKAttributeMapping: 0x7b9437d0 deleted => shouldBeDeleted>",
    "<RKAttributeMapping: 0x7b9437e0 start_date => start_date>",
    "<RKAttributeMapping: 0x7b943b40 follow_up_id => follow_up_id>",
    "<RKRelationshipMapping: 0x7bfa2310 tags => tags>",
    "<RKRelationshipMapping: 0x7bfa64c0 required_participants => required_participants>",
    "<RKRelationshipMapping: 0x7bfa7b90 optional_participants => optional_participants>",
    "<RKRelationshipMapping: 0x7bfa9280 readonly_participants => readonly_participants>",
    "<RKRelationshipMapping: 0x7bfaa970 organizer => organizer>",
    "<RKRelationshipMapping: 0x7bea9470 meeting_topics => meeting_topics>"
)>
2014-11-24 22:04:25.114 myapp[15398:836040] D restkit.object_mapping:RKMappingOperation.m:952 Starting mapping operation...
2014-11-24 22:04:25.115 myapp[15398:836040] T restkit:RKObjectMapping.m:525 Attempting to parse string '2014-11-24T16:40:05Z' with format string 'yyyy-MM-dd' and time zone 'GMT (GMT) offset 0'
2014-11-24 22:04:25.116 myapp[15398:836040] T restkit:RKObjectMapping.m:525 Attempting to parse string '2014-11-24T16:40:05Z' with format string 'yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'' and time zone 'GMT (GMT) offset 0'
2014-11-24 22:04:25.117 myapp[15398:836040] T restkit:RKObjectMapping.m:534 Successfully parsed string '2014-11-24T16:40:05Z' with format string 'yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'' and time zone 'GMT (GMT) offset 0' and turned into date '2014-11-24 16:40:05 +0000'
2014-11-24 22:04:25.118 myapp[15398:836040] T restkit:RKObjectMapping.m:525 Attempting to parse string '2014-11-24T15:40:05Z' with format string 'yyyy-MM-dd' and time zone 'GMT (GMT) offset 0'
2014-11-24 22:04:25.119 myapp[15398:836040] T restkit:RKObjectMapping.m:525 Attempting to parse string '2014-11-24T15:40:05Z' with format string 'yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'' and time zone 'GMT (GMT) offset 0'
2014-11-24 22:04:25.122 myapp[15398:836040] T restkit:RKObjectMapping.m:534 Successfully parsed string '2014-11-24T15:40:05Z' with format string 'yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'' and time zone 'GMT (GMT) offset 0' and turned into date '2014-11-24 15:40:05 +0000'
2014-11-24 22:04:25.128 myapp[15398:836184] D restkit.core_data:RKPropertyInspector+CoreData.m:112 Cached property inspection for Entity '(<NSEntityDescription: 0x7a783960>) name DBMeetings, managedObjectClassName DBMeetings, renamingIdentifier DBMeetings, isAbstract 0, superentity name (null), properties {
    "created_at" = "(<NSAttributeDescription: 0x7a7390a0>), name created_at, isOptional 1, isTransient 0, entity DBMeetings, renamingIdentifier created_at, validation predicates (\n), warnings (\n), versionHashModifier (null)\n userInfo {\n}, attributeType 900 , attributeValueClassName NSDate, defaultValue (null)";
    "finish_date" = "(<NSAttributeDescription: 0x7a783ec0>), name finish_date, isOptional 1, isTransient 0, entity DBMeetings, renamingIdentifier finish_date, validation predicates (\n), warnings (\n), versionHashModifier (null)\n userInfo {\n}, attributeType 900 , attributeValueClassName NSDate, defaultValue (null)";
    "finish_time" = "(<NSAttributeDescription: 0x7a7329f0>), name finish_time, isOptional 1, isTransient 0, entity DBMeetings, renamingIdentifier finish_time, validation predicates (\n), warnings (\n), versionHashModifier (null)\n userInfo {\n}, attributeType 900 , attributeValueClassName NSDate, defaultValue (null)";
    "follow_up_id" = "(<NSAttributeDescription: 0x7a7a3910>), name follow_up_id, isOptional 1, isTransient 0, entity DBMeetings, renamingIdentifier follow_up_id, validation predicates (\n), warnings (\n), versionHashModifier (null)\n userInfo {\n}, attributeType 200 , attributeValueClassName NSNumber, defaultValue 0";
    id = "(<NSAttributeDescription: 0x7a7846a0>), name id, isOptional 1, isTransient 0, entity DBMeetings, renamingIdentifier id, validation predicates (\n), warnings (\n), versionHashModifier (null)\n userInfo {\n}, attributeType 200 , attributeValueClassName NSNumber, defaultValue 0";
    "is_synced" = "(<NSAttributeDescription: 0x7a733ec0>), name is_synced, isOptional 1, isTransient 0, entity DBMeetings, renamingIdentifier is_synced, validation predicates (\n), warnings (\n), versionHashModifier (null)\n userInfo {\n}, attributeType 800 , attributeValueClassName NSNumber, defaultValue 1";
    location = "(<NSAttributeDescription: 0x7a774fa0>), name location, isOptional 1, isTransient 0, entity DBMeetings, renamingIdentifier location, validation predicates (\n), warnings (\n), versionHashModifier (null)\n userInfo {\n}, attributeType 700 , attributeValueClassName NSString, defaultValue (null)";
    lock = "(<NSAttributeDescription: 0x7a7487f0>), name lock, isOptional 1, isTransient 0, entity DBMeetings, renamingIdentifier lock, validation predicates (\n), warnings (\n), versionHashModifier (null)\n userInfo {\n}, attributeType 800 , attributeValueClassName NSNumber, defaultValue (null)";
    "meeting_topics" = "(<NSRelationshipDescription: 0x7a744930>), name meeting_topics, isOptional 1, isTransient 0, entity DBMeetings, renamingIdentifier meeting_topics, validation predicates (\n), warnings (\n), versionHashModifier (null)\n userInfo {\n}, destination entity DBTopics, inverseRelationship meeting, minCount 0, maxCount 0, isOrdered 0, deleteRule 1";
    "optional_participants" = "(<NSRelationshipDescription: 0x7a74dbf0>), name optional_participants, isOptional 1, isTransient 0, entity DBMeetings, renamingIdentifier optional_participants, validation predicates (\n), warnings (\n), versionHashModifier (null)\n userInfo {\n}, destination entity DBMembers, inverseRelationship meeting_optional_participants, minCount 0, maxCount 0, isOrdered 0, deleteRule 1";
    organizer = "(<NSRelationshipDescription: 0x7a7448d0>), name organizer, isOptional 1, isTransient 0, entity DBMeetings, renamingIdentifier organizer, validation predicates (\n), warnings (\n), versionHashModifier (null)\n userInfo {\n}, destination entity DBMembers, inverseRelationship meetings_organizer, minCount 0, maxCount 1, isOrdered 0, deleteRule 1";
    "parent_meeting_id" = "(<NSAttributeDescription: 0x7a743fe0>), name parent_meeting_id, isOptional 1, isTransient 0, entity DBMeetings, renamingIdentifier parent_meeting_id, validation predicates (\n), warnings (\n), versionHashModifier (null)\n userInfo {\n}, attributeType 200 , attributeValueClassName NSNumber, defaultValue 0";
    "parent_meeting_title" = "(<NSAttributeDescription: 0x7a7158f0>), name parent_meeting_title, isOptional 1, isTransient 0, entity DBMeetings, renamingIdentifier parent_meeting_title, validation predicates (\n), warnings (\n), versionHashModifier (null)\n userInfo {\n}, attributeType 700 , attributeValueClassName NSString, defaultValue (null)";
    "readonly_participants" = "(<NSRelationshipDescription: 0x7a74dc50>), name readonly_participants, isOptional 1, isTransient 0, entity DBMeetings, renamingIdentifier readonly_participants, validation predicates (\n), warnings (\n), versionHashModifier (null)\n userInfo {\n}, destination entity DBMembers, inverseRelationship meeting_readonly_participants, minCount 0, maxCount 0, isOrdered 0, deleteRule 1";
    "required_participants" = "(<NSRelationshipDescription: 0x7a754180>), name required_participants, isOptional 1, isTransient 0, entity DBMeetings, renamingIdentifier required_participants, validation predicates (\n), warnings (\n), versionHashModifier (null)\n userInfo {\n}, destination entity DBMembers, inverseRelationship meeting_required_participants, minCount 0, maxCount 0, isOrdered 0, deleteRule 1";
    sample = "(<NSAttributeDescription: 0x7a715940>), name sample, isOptional 1, isTransient 0, entity DBMeetings, renamingIdentifier sample, validation predicates (\n), warnings (\n), versionHashModifier (null)\n userInfo {\n}, attributeType 800 , attributeValueClassName NSNumber, defaultValue (null)";
    shouldBeDeleted = "(<NSAttributeDescription: 0x7a722730>), name shouldBeDeleted, isOptional 1, isTransient 0, entity DBMeetings, renamingIdentifier shouldBeDeleted, validation predicates (\n), warnings (\n), versionHashModifier (null)\n userInfo {\n}, attributeType 800 , attributeValueClassName NSNumber, defaultValue (null)";
    "start_date" = "(<NSAttributeDescription: 0x7a722780>), name start_date, isOptional 1, isTransient 0, entity DBMeetings, renamingIdentifier start_date, validation predicates (\n), warnings (\n), versionHashModifier (null)\n userInfo {\n}, attributeType 900 , attributeValueClassName NSDate, defaultValue (null)";
    "start_time" = "(<NSAttributeDescription: 0x7a77b720>), name start_time, isOptional 1, isTransient 0, entity DBMeetings, renamingIdentifier start_time, validation predicates (\n), warnings (\n), versionHashModifier (null)\n userInfo {\n}, attributeType 900 , attributeValueClassName NSDate, defaultValue (null)";
    tags = "(<NSRelationshipDescription: 0x7a7541e0>), name tags, isOptional 1, isTransient 0, entity DBMeetings, renamingIdentifier tags, validation predicates (\n), warnings (\n), versionHashModifier (null)\n userInfo {\n}, destination entity DBTags, inverseRelationship meetings, minCount 0, maxCount 0, isOrdered 0, deleteRule 1";
    title = "(<NSAttributeDescription: 0x7a77b770>), name title, isOptional 1, isTransient 0, entity DBMeetings, renamingIdentifier title, validation predicates (\n), warnings (\n), versionHashModifier (null)\n userInfo {\n}, attributeType 700 , attributeValueClassName NSString, defaultValue (null)";
    "topics_updated_at" = "(<NSAttributeDescription: 0x7a70cf10>), name topics_updated_at, isOptional 1, isTransient 0, entity DBMeetings, renamingIdentifier topics_updated_at, validation predicates (\n), warnings (\n), versionHashModifier (null)\n userInfo {\n}, attributeType 900 , attributeValueClassName NSDate, defaultValue (null)";
    "total_topics" = "(<NSAttributeDescription: 0x7a70cf60>), name total_topics, isOptional 1, isTransient 0, entity DBMeetings, renamingIdentifier total_topics, validation predicates (\n), warnings (\n), versionHashModifier (null)\n userInfo {\n}, attributeType 200 , attributeValueClassName NSNumber, defaultValue 0";
    "updated_at" = "(<NSAttributeDescription: 0x7a734600>), name updated_at, isOptional 1, isTransient 0, entity DBMeetings, renamingIdentifier updated_at, validation predicates (\n), warnings (\n), versionHashModifier (null)\n userInfo {\n}, attributeType 900 , attributeValueClassName NSDate, defaultValue (null)";
}, subentities {
}, userInfo {
}, versionHashModifier (null)': {
    "created_at" =     {
        isPrimitive = 0;
        keyValueCodingClass = NSDate;
        name = "created_at";
    };
    "finish_date" =     {
        isPrimitive = 0;
        keyValueCodingClass = NSDate;
        name = "finish_date";
    };
    "finish_time" =     {
        isPrimitive = 0;
        keyValueCodingClass = NSDate;
        name = "finish_time";
    };
    "follow_up_id" =     {
        isPrimitive = 0;
        keyValueCodingClass = NSNumber;
        name = "follow_up_id";
    };
    id =     {
        isPrimitive = 0;
        keyValueCodingClass = NSNumber;
        name = id;
    };
    "is_synced" =     {
        isPrimitive = 0;
        keyValueCodingClass = "__NSCFBoolean";
        name = "is_synced";
    };
    location =     {
        isPrimitive = 0;
        keyValueCodingClass = NSString;
        name = location;
    };
    lock =     {
        isPrimitive = 0;
        keyValueCodingClass = "__NSCFBoolean";
        name = lock;
    };
    "meeting_topics" =     {
        isPrimitive = 0;
        keyValueCodingClass = NSSet;
        name = "meeting_topics";
    };
    "optional_participants" =     {
        isPrimitive = 0;
        keyValueCodingClass = NSSet;
        name = "optional_participants";
    };
    organizer =     {
        isPrimitive = 0;
        keyValueCodingClass = DBMembers;
        name = organizer;
    };
    "parent_meeting_id" =     {
        isPrimitive = 0;
        keyValueCodingClass = NSNumber;
        name = "parent_meeting_id";
    };
    "parent_meeting_title" =     {
        isPrimitive = 0;
        keyValueCodingClass = NSString;
        name = "parent_meeting_title";
    };
    "readonly_participants" =     {
        isPrimitive = 0;
        keyValueCodingClass = NSSet;
        name = "readonly_participants";
    };
    "required_participants" =     {
        isPrimitive = 0;
        keyValueCodingClass = NSSet;
        name = "required_participants";
    };
    sample =     {
        isPrimitive = 0;
        keyValueCodingClass = "__NSCFBoolean";
        name = sample;
    };
    shouldBeDeleted =     {
        isPrimitive = 0;
        keyValueCodingClass = "__NSCFBoolean";
        name = shouldBeDeleted;
    };
    "start_date" =     {
        isPrimitive = 0;
        keyValueCodingClass = NSDate;
        name = "start_date";
    };
    "start_time" =     {
        isPrimitive = 0;
        keyValueCodingClass = NSDate;
        name = "start_time";
    };
    tags =     {
        isPrimitive = 0;
        keyValueCodingClass = NSSet;
        name = tags;
    };
    title =     {
        isPrimitive = 0;
        keyValueCodingClass = NSString;
        name = title;
    };
    "topics_updated_at" =     {
        isPrimitive = 0;
        keyValueCodingClass = NSDate;
        name = "topics_updated_at";
    };
    "total_topics" =     {
        isPrimitive = 0;
        keyValueCodingClass = NSNumber;
        name = "total_topics";
    };
    "updated_at" =     {
        isPrimitive = 0;
        keyValueCodingClass = NSDate;
        name = "updated_at";
    };
}
2014-11-24 22:04:25.133 myapp[15398:836040] T restkit:RKObjectMapping.m:525 Attempting to parse string '2014-11-24T20:40:05+05:00' with format string 'yyyy-MM-dd' and time zone 'GMT (GMT) offset 0'
2014-11-24 22:04:25.134 myapp[15398:836040] T restkit:RKObjectMapping.m:525 Attempting to parse string '2014-11-24T20:40:05+05:00' with format string 'yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'' and time zone 'GMT (GMT) offset 0'
2014-11-24 22:04:25.135 myapp[15398:836040] T restkit:RKObjectMapping.m:525 Attempting to parse string '2014-11-24T20:40:05+05:00' with format string 'MM/dd/yyyy' and time zone 'GMT (GMT) offset 0'
2014-11-24 22:04:25.137 myapp[15398:836040] T restkit:RKObjectMapping.m:525 Attempting to parse string '2014-11-24T20:40:05+05:00' with format string 'yyyy-MM-dd' and time zone 'GMT (GMT) offset 0'
2014-11-24 22:04:25.138 myapp[15398:836040] T restkit:RKObjectMapping.m:525 Attempting to parse string '2014-11-24T20:40:05+05:00' with format string 'yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'' and time zone 'GMT (GMT) offset 0'
2014-11-24 22:04:25.139 myapp[15398:836040] T restkit:RKObjectMapping.m:525 Attempting to parse string '2014-11-24T20:40:05+05:00' with format string 'MM/dd/yyyy' and time zone 'GMT (GMT) offset 0'
2014-11-24 22:04:25.140 myapp[15398:836040] D restkit.object_mapping:RKMappingOperation.m:740 Mapping one to many relationship value at keyPath 'tags' to 'tags'
2014-11-24 22:04:25.141 myapp[15398:836040] D restkit.object_mapping:RKMappingOperation.m:740 Mapping one to many relationship value at keyPath 'required_participants' to 'required_participants'
2014-11-24 22:04:25.141 myapp[15398:836040] D restkit.object_mapping:RKMappingOperation.m:740 Mapping one to many relationship value at keyPath 'optional_participants' to 'optional_participants'
2014-11-24 22:04:25.142 myapp[15398:836040] D restkit.object_mapping:RKMappingOperation.m:740 Mapping one to many relationship value at keyPath 'readonly_participants' to 'readonly_participants'
2014-11-24 22:04:25.142 myapp[15398:836040] D restkit.object_mapping:RKMappingOperation.m:683 Mapping one to one relationship value at keyPath 'organizer' to 'organizer'
2014-11-24 22:04:25.145 myapp[15398:836040] D restkit.core_data:RKFetchRequestManagedObjectCache.m:124 Found objects '(
)' using fetchRequest '<NSFetchRequest: 0x7b9a75d0> (entity: DBMembers; predicate: (id == 43031); sortDescriptors: ((null)); type: NSManagedObjectResultType; )'
2014-11-24 22:04:25.144 myapp[15398:836184] D restkit.object_mapping:RKPropertyInspector.m:130 Cached property inspection for Class 'DBMembers': {
    "created_at" =     {
        isPrimitive = 0;
        keyValueCodingClass = NSDate;
        name = "created_at";
    };
    email =     {
        isPrimitive = 0;
        keyValueCodingClass = NSString;
        name = email;
    };
    "first_name" =     {
        isPrimitive = 0;
        keyValueCodingClass = NSString;
        name = "first_name";
    };
    hide =     {
        isPrimitive = 0;
        keyValueCodingClass = NSNumber;
        name = hide;
    };
    id =     {
        isPrimitive = 0;
        keyValueCodingClass = NSNumber;
        name = id;
    };
    "last_name" =     {
        isPrimitive = 0;
        keyValueCodingClass = NSString;
        name = "last_name";
    };
    "meeting_optional_participants" =     {
        isPrimitive = 0;
        keyValueCodingClass = NSSet;
        name = "meeting_optional_participants";
    };
    "meeting_readonly_participants" =     {
        isPrimitive = 0;
        keyValueCodingClass = NSSet;
        name = "meeting_readonly_participants";
    };
    "meeting_required_participants" =     {
        isPrimitive = 0;
        keyValueCodingClass = NSSet;
        name = "meeting_required_participants";
    };
    "meetings_organizer" =     {
        isPrimitive = 0;
        keyValueCodingClass = NSSet;
        name = "meetings_organizer";
    };
    name =     {
        isPrimitive = 0;
        keyValueCodingClass = NSString;
        name = name;
    };
    "tag_members" =     {
        isPrimitive = 0;
        keyValueCodingClass = NSSet;
        name = "tag_members";
    };
    "tag_owner" =     {
        isPrimitive = 0;
        keyValueCodingClass = NSSet;
        name = "tag_owner";
    };
    tasks =     {
        isPrimitive = 0;
        keyValueCodingClass = NSSet;
        name = tasks;
    };
    "tasks_additional_owner" =     {
        isPrimitive = 0;
        keyValueCodingClass = NSSet;
        name = "tasks_additional_owner";
    };
    "topics_presenter" =     {
        isPrimitive = 0;
        keyValueCodingClass = NSSet;
        name = "topics_presenter";
    };
    type =     {
        isPrimitive = 0;
        keyValueCodingClass = NSString;
        name = type;
    };
    "updated_at" =     {
        isPrimitive = 0;
        keyValueCodingClass = NSDate;
        name = "updated_at";
    };
    "user_id" =     {
        isPrimitive = 0;
        keyValueCodingClass = NSNumber;
        name = "user_id";
    };
}
2014-11-24 22:04:25.149 myapp[15398:836040] D restkit.object_mapping:RKMappingOperation.m:952 Starting mapping operation...
2014-11-24 22:04:25.150 myapp[15398:836040] D restkit.object_mapping:RKMappingOperation.m:1021 Finished mapping operation successfully...
2014-11-24 22:04:25.152 myapp[15398:836040] D restkit.object_mapping:RKMappingOperation.m:830 Did not find mappable relationship value keyPath 'meeting_topics'
2014-11-24 22:04:25.153 myapp[15398:836040] D restkit.object_mapping:RKMappingOperation.m:1021 Finished mapping operation successfully...
2014-11-24 22:04:25.155 myapp[15398:836040] D restkit.object_mapping:RKMapperOperation.m:403 Finished performing object mapping. Results: {
    "" =     (
        "<DBMeetings: 0x7b8a7de0> (entity: DBMeetings; id: 0x7b8a7a80 <x-coredata:///DBMeetings/tB264A525-7D9C-4510-B9C1-6F532CDEE3012> ; data: {\n    \"created_at\" = \"2014-11-24 15:40:05 +0000\";\n    \"finish_date\" = nil;\n    \"finish_time\" = \"2014-11-24 16:40:05 +0000\";\n    \"follow_up_id\" = nil;\n    id = 92465;\n    \"is_synced\" = 1;\n    location = nil;\n    lock = 0;\n    \"meeting_topics\" =     (\n    );\n    \"optional_participants\" =     (\n    );\n    organizer = \"0x7b9a8260 <x-coredata:///DBMembers/tB264A525-7D9C-4510-B9C1-6F532CDEE3013>\";\n    \"parent_meeting_id\" = nil;\n    \"parent_meeting_title\" = nil;\n    \"readonly_participants\" =     (\n    );\n    \"required_participants\" =     (\n    );\n    sample = 0;\n    shouldBeDeleted = 0;\n    \"start_date\" = nil;\n    \"start_time\" = \"2014-11-24 15:40:05 +0000\";\n    tags =     (\n    );\n    title = \"Untitled Meeting\";\n    \"topics_updated_at\" = nil;\n    \"total_topics\" = 0;\n    \"updated_at\" = \"2014-11-24 15:40:05 +0000\";\n})"
    );
}
(lldb)
```

JSON is downloaded and `DBMeetings` object is mapped, but block never calls.

This seems to be related to this issue

https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/issues/2029

Any help is appreciated.

Here are some screenshots.
[image]
[image]

Comment: Found the issue, crashing only when I am using in mapping `deletionPredicate`. Still looking for solution.

Comment: You haven't shown any exception stack trace / message (and provided details of your deletion predicate and data model)

Comment: @Wain unfortunately, there is no more detail in Log. I have added a couple of screenshots, please let me know if I can provide anything more.